# Cannot understand why my solution is not passing certain test cases in HackerRank's 'Count Triplets' problem

Tags: c#, algorithm

The problem description is [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/count-triplets-1/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps)

And in case the above link breaks in the future

[image]

My solution is:

```
private static long GetNumberOfTriplets(IEnumerable<long> array, long ratio)
{
    var frequencyByInteger = array
        .GroupBy(item => item)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.LongCount());

    /*  If ratio is 1, then all the items in the triplet are equal.
     *  This formula can be derived from n(n+1)/2 via induction.
     *  But you don't need to understand this in order to help me,
     *  as the failing test cases are using ratio != 1.
     */
    if (ratio == 1) return frequencyByInteger.Values.Sum(v => v * (v - 1) * (v - 2) / 6);

    /*  Looping through each distinct number, then checking if the
     *  dictionary has the other 2 numbers necessary to form a triplet.
     *  The frequencies of the three numbers are then 
     *  multiplied with each other in order to handle all 
     *  combinations in the case of repeated numbers.
     *  E.g. in the array {1, 1, 3, 3, 9, 9}
     *  there are 2*2*2=8 combinations of (1, 3, 9).
     */
    return frequencyByInteger.Keys
        .Where(v => frequencyByInteger.ContainsKey(v * ratio)
                    && frequencyByInteger.ContainsKey(v * ratio * ratio))
        .Sum(v => frequencyByInteger[v] * frequencyByInteger[v * ratio] * frequencyByInteger[v * ratio * ratio]);
}
```

It fails on test cases 6 and 10. I cannot verify the test cases manually, as there are 100 000 integers in both of them.

My solution finds 13 621 903 916 triplets for test case 6, but HackerRank expects 2 325 652 489 triplets. I'm off by around 11 billion, basically.

The file for test case 6 is [here](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/70878/input06.txt?response-content-type=text%2Fplain&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV%2F20231111%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231111T225404Z&X-Amz-Expires=7200&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=d581c2f98c2d151f87b8383a9497eaef48f8eb0d4e13a20776223266504ae7c8)

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes, I seem to have confused myself over the description! I agree, they could have done better with the description and the example. Thanks for the help, @user3386109!

Comment: @user3386109, can you write that as an answer? I want to accept it in order to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in the image is not very good. It doesn't have repeated elements, and the elements are in sorted order. But the problem description doesn't state that the elements are always sorted.

Consider the array `[4,16,1]` with r=4. Does that array have 0 or 1 triplet?

Or `[1,4,16,4]`. Is that 1 or 2 triplets?

The question does say that `i < j < k`, but doesn't explicitly state that `a[i] < a[j] < a[k]`. If that's required, then that would explain why your code over-counts.

Comment: After solving this on Hackerrank, I can confirm that it is indeed expecting `a[i] < a[j] < a[k]`. Poor problem statement from them by the way. And yes, array need not be sorted, but it shouldn't matter.